# How to use TortoiseSVN to get files that under a specific version

Tags: file, tortoisesvn, version

Hi currenlty i'm start to use TortoiseSVN, before that i'm using CVS.

Assuming, we have concurrent changes on the same project and each of the changes need to release in different time.

In CVS, when we need to commit a file and we would write down some message in message text box(assume i put in CR00001) and then when we deploying the application, we just get all files that with message equal ='CR0001'. So we've no worry about wrong version to release.

Is there a way for me to do this in TortoiseSVN?

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use TortoiseSVN to update to a specific revision.

For what you're trying to do, though, consider creating a RELEASE branch of the code, then use [svnmerge](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) to manage the promotion of specific changesets.